# Trigonometric Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to show that 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {\arctan{(1/k^2)}}
$$
converges?
I would prefer to avoid the integral test.

Can I find a more notorious convergent series that limit mine from above?

Comment: Presumably $k$ and $n$ are somehow related?

Answer (score 11):

Remember that $\lvert\arctan x\rvert \le |x|$...

Comment: Oh, true!! Thanks!!